# How to run Auto Hot Key file from web Page?

Tags: autohotkey

Is there any way to call or run .ahk files from web page using any of (HTML - JS - PHP)?
 I need to start ahk files from my web pages on link or button clicks

Comment: Basically possible, but what exactly are you trying to achieve? On which computer is the script supposed to run when the user clicks the "link"? On your server or on the users computer? Does it have to work in every browser? Is your server on linux or windows? Does it have to to work only for your computer or does it need to work for any computer accessing the "website"?

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example of how it can be done by using some evil activeX. 
It used to be possible to access a users whole computer using activeX in the Internet Explorer. Nowadays ActiveX is mostly disabled. But we can still create .hta files to render html etc and these files allow the usage of activeX.

Try to save this as something.hta

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
    <meta http-equiv='X-UA-Compatible' content='IE=9'>
    <script language="JScript">window.resizeTo(200,100);</script> 
    <script language="JScript">
        function runAhkScript() {
            var ahkExePath = "C:/Program Files/AutoHotkey/AutoHotkey.exe";
            var scriptToExecute = "C:/aaa/a.ahk";
            new ActiveXObject("Shell.Application").ShellExecute(ahkExePath, scriptToExecute)
        }
    </script>
</head>

<body>
    <a href="#" onclick="runAhkScript()">Run the autohotkey script</a>
</body>
```

Adjust the path to your autohotkey.exe and your script and make sure you use forward slashes in the pathes.

Comment: Thanks. that's cool but i basically need to open them from my project files (php - html) so .hta files won't be useful

Comment: You have to be more specific, otherwise I can't really help you.

Comment: I mean no one can use .hta files in web projects. so i need a code that really works from .html or .php page extension which can work on firefox without problems

Comment: Why don't you just answer the comment that I posted right below your question?

Answer (score -1):

You can not do that while accessing your web pages over a remote server (even localhost).  If you access your web page on your local machine (i.e., typing "`file:///C:/path/my web page.html`" in the browser), and you **use Internet Explorer as your browser**, you might try:

```
    <button onclick="window.open('file:///C:/path/my ahk script.ahk')">
        Launch My AHK Script
    </button>
```

Or, you may have to try it this way:

```
    <button onclick="Process.Start('C:\path\my ahk script.ahk')">
        Launch My AHK Script
    </button>
```

(But maybe switch the slashes to "`/`" or add "`file:\\`" (trying with two or three slashes, and in each direction).

Hth,

Comment: I've tried what you said but it didn't launch the ahk file. instead the ahk script has been displayed as text in browser page.

Comment: Hmmm.  OK, then try `onclick="Process.Start('C:\path\my ahk script.ahk')"`  In this case, you may have to play with the slashes (change to "/") or even add the "file:\\" prefix (try with one, two or three slashes, and in each direction).  Let me know what works and I'll edit my answer accordingly.  Hth,

Comment: Are you using Internet Explorer for your browser?  Afaik that is the only browser that these usually work in (and I have edited my answer accordingly).

Comment: Also, I tried it again.  "window.open('file:///C:/path/my ahk script.ahk')" works for me (but I have the ahk extensions associated with ahk).  I do get a message at the bottom of the IE browser saying "Do you want to open or save **my ahk script.ahk**" but when I click the "Open" button, the script runs.